# Leaking Doorframe

Tags: doors, waterproofing, door-frame, old-house

Just bought a home, rental, and tenant recently sent me video of the back doorway leaking through the bit of wood that stops the door from closing during a heavy rain.  There is definitely caulk cracked in the area that the water is leaking through.  Thinking a new doorframe should fix the issue?

Comment: pictures would help.  From your description there is a water control issue.  or you have no weatherstripping on the door frame. If it isn't a bad wind driven rain storm, the rain should not come through.   I have seen stupid things like an interior door used on an exterior exit. also.

Comment: Gotta storm door?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.